# CMD to established text file without overwriting & on it's own line

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm in a bit of a pickle and a time crunch. Having some issues with the following:

I have a pre-established txt file. I'm needing to run a couple of generic command prompts that will then be added ONTOP of the pre-existing data within the said file without overwriting. Also, I need info added before output. For example, let's hypothetically say I'm using the following two commands within Windows 7:

```
tzutil /g
&
hostname
```

Will give the output of:

```
US Mountain Standard Time
&
MyComputer
```

I need to add those two outputs within lines of their own, ONTOP of the pre-existing data of the file. These are to basically be used as header information. I also need tags in front of the outputs, for example:

```
timezone:US Mountain Standard Time
hostname:MyComputer
ORIGINAL DATA NOT TO BE OVERWRITTEN
ORIGINAL DATA NOT TO BE OVERWRITTEN
ORIGINAL DATA NOT TO BE OVERWRITTEN
ORIGINAL DATA NOT TO BE OVERWRITTEN
```

Any help would be appreciated, just trying to find the most practical way of doing this. I keep running into multiple issues whenever I attempt to do so.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried and tell us what you specifically have troubles with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is the following command lines ([cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)):

```cmd
(< nul set /P ="timezone:" & tzutil /G & echo/& < nul set /P ="hostname:" & hostname & more +2 "file.txt") > "file.txt.tmp"
move /Y "file.txt.tmp" "file.txt"
```

As a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) I would write it like this:

```cmd
(
    < nul set /P ="timezone:"     & rem // (write text without line-break at the end)
    tzutil /G                     & rem // (write the time zone name)
    echo/&                          rem // (append a line-break since `tzutil` does not)
    < nul set /P ="hostname:"     & rem // (write text without line-break at the end)
    hostname                      & rem // (write the host name with trailing line-break)
    more +2 "file.txt"            & rem // (return file content except first two lines)
) > "file.txt.tmp"                & rem // (redirect to a temporary file)
move /Y "file.txt.tmp" "file.txt" & rem // (move temporary file onto original one)
```

Note that the input file must contain less than 64K lines, each of which must be shorter than 64K characters.

Answer (score 1):

Print your header into a new file then TYPE whatever needs to go after the header from your existing file. You can then REN the new file with the old file's filename to achieve your desired result. I don't know any other way of doing this in batch.

For tags in front of the outputs, try:

```
FOR /F %%A IN ('tzutil /g') DO ECHO timezone:%%A >> output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done my writing the first two lines, then copying everything except the first two lines from the current file. This is written to a temporary file which will be moved to the original filename.

Change the value of THEFILE to your filename.

=== repheader.bat

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
SET "THEFILE=C:\src\t\currentfile.txt"
SET "TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\repheader.tmp"

(   FOR /F %%A IN ('TZUTIL /g') DO (ECHO timezone:%%~A)
    FOR /F %%A IN ('hostname') DO (ECHO hostname:%%~A)
    FOR /F "delims= skip=2" %%A IN ('TYPE "%THEFILE%"') DO (ECHO %%~A)
) >"%TEMPFILE%"

MOVE /Y "%TEMPFILE%" "%THEFILE%"
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B 0
```

Answer (score 0):

just in case you were serious about wanting a powershell solution, here is one ... [*grin*]

what it does ...

- sets the file name to use
- creates the file for testing
  when you are ready to use your own test file, remove or disable the entire `#region/#endregion` block.
- gets the time zone, the host name, and the content of the target file
  this does not show the tz offset OR the standard/daylight status.
- creates a `here-string` for the 3 values & fills those values in
- trims away the two blank lines that somehow get added
- sends the new content to the old file
  this overwrites the original. that makes me nervous ... you may want to add a backup step to preserve the original.

the code ...

```
$InFile = "$env:TEMP\JonnyDavy_KeepOrignalLines.txt"

#region >>> create a test file
#    when ready to do this for real, remove the entire "#region/#endregion" block
@'
1st line to keep.
Line to keep, the 2nd.
Third one.
Last to keep.
'@ | Set-Content -LiteralPath $InFile
#endregion >>> create a test file

$TimeZone = (Get-TimeZone).Id
$HostName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$FileContent = Get-Content -LiteralPath $InFile -Raw

(@'
TimeZone : {0}
HostName : {1}
{2}
'@ -f $TimeZone, $HostName, $FileContent).Trim() |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $InFile
```

content of the re-written file ...

```
TimeZone : Central Standard Time
HostName : [MySysName]
1st line to keep.
Line to keep, the 2nd.
Third one.
Last to keep.
```